# how to add "... read more" anchor to end of text if it does not fit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a way to add `"... read more"` hyperlink to end of visible part of multi-line text if its height exceeds 8em.

I tried code below but `... read more` does not appear and only half of last line height is visible.

How to make it to appear and allow user to click in it?

#### something like:

```
asd sadas sads asda dfdsf
dfds sdf ... read more


.description
{
    max-height: 8em;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: small;
    text-overflow: "<a href='details'>... read more</a>";
}

<p class='description'>dsdsa sakldlka asld slkskldsdlks ewekesdsdjkdj skskssk skssksk skssksks sksksks sksksjs sksks kassaksk skdksk skdskdj askdasj asdkasjd asldksa lasd askla dasl asldaksd lad askdal adslkaskd lads askaldka alsdkaslda  adkalsdk adsdkasl adklasdl kaldakd aas dasdklasdask asldkaslsdk asldsakdl
kassaksk skdksk skdskdjff askdasj asdkasjd asldksa lasd askla dasl asldaksd lad askdal adslkaskd lads askaldka alsdsdkaslda  adkalsdk adsdkasl adklasdl kaldakd aas dasdklasdask asldkaslsdk asldsakdl
sad kassaksk skdksk skdskdj askdasj asdkasjd asldksa lasd askla dasl asldaksd lad askdal adslkaskd lads askaldka alsdkaslda ff adkalsdk fffadsdkasl adklasdl kaldakd aas dasdklasdask asldkaslsdk asldsakdl
fddfkassaksk skdfdfksk skdskdj askdasj asdkasjd asldksa lasd askla dasl asldaksd lad askdal adslkaskd lads askaldka alsdkaslda  adkalsdk adsdkasl adklasdl kaldakd aas dasdklasdask asldkaslsdk asldsakdl</p>
```

Comment: Looks like you're looking for `text-overflow : ellipsis;`, but clickable "read more" links with toggle effect would probably require javascript.

Comment: Tried `text-overflow: ellipsis` but it does not work. Tried also `text-overflow: "<a href='details'>... read more</a>"` but nothing appears. Visual Studio writes that text-overflow is unknow property name. It works probably for single line text only.

Comment: Maybe you should try something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ymGZB/) ???

Comment: Thank you. This is single line text. How to implement this for multi-line text?

Comment: Linked to - [CSS Text ellipsis including "More" link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77134144/104380)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need jQuery / (server side language) for this. It cant be done with pure css.

[dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) is very nice jquery plugin for the same purpose. (Scroll bottom for `Read more` example)

Comment: Than you very much. I tried `        $(function () {
            $('.description').dotdotdot({
                after: 'a.more',
                height: 880
            });` and `<a href="details" class="more">Read more &raquo;</a>` 
It adds `read more` even if full text is visible (ellipsis are not added in this case). How to add read more only if there is more text?

Answer (score 3):

This feels somewhat clunky, and requires some manipulation of the DOM, but I'd suggest:

```
$('p').each(function (i, e) {
    var that = $(this);
    that.contents().wrapAll('<span class="pWrap" />');
    var span = that.find('span.pWrap'),
        sHeight = span.height();
    that.data({
        'fullHeight': sHeight,
            'minHeight': that.height()
    });
    if (that.height() < sHeight) {
        $('<a />', {
            'href': '#',
                'text': 'read more',
                'class': 'readMore'
        }).appendTo(that);
    }
}).on('click', 'a.readMore', function (e) {
    var that = $(this),
        p = $(this).closest('p'),
        fullHeight = p.data('fullHeight') + 40,
        minHeight = p.data('minHeight'),
        toHeight = p.height() == fullHeight ? minHeight : fullHeight;
    p.animate({
        'max-height': toHeight,
            'height': toHeight
    }, 1000);
    that.text(function (i, t) {
        return t == 'read more' ? 'show less' : 'read more';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uRajF/1/).

References:

- [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PHP function I wrote to do this, not sure what language you want to use:

```
<?php
function read_more($article_text, $limit=50)
{
  $breakpoint = 0;
   if(strlen($article_text) > $limit)
   {
      if( ($breakpoint = strpos($article_text, ".", $limit)) !== false )
      {
         if( $breakpoint < strlen($article_text) - 1 )
         {
            $article_text = substr($article_text, 0, $breakpoint) . '... <span class="read_more">[&nbsp;<a href="'.$article_link.'">Read&nbsp;More</a>&nbsp;]</span>';
         }
      }
   }
   return $article_text;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. How you solved the issuse that on certain browsers and certain screen sizes only part of last line height is visible ? How to implement vertical wrapping so that last line is always fully visible ?

Answer (score 0):

CSS is enough, no need for JS.

Relative positioned wrapper and absolute positioned read-more-link with opaque background.

Bonus: Display the clamped text by clicking on the link.

```css
.description-wrapper {
    position: relative
}

.description {
    -webkit-line-clamp: initial
}

.trimmed-description-wrapper .description {
    display: -webkit-box;
    text-overflow: fade;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    overflow: hidden
}

.trimmed-description-wrapper .read-more-link {
    display:initial;
}

.read-more-link {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: coral;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-tecoration: underline;
    background: #fff
}

.read-more-link::before {
    content: "...";
    color: #484848;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 8px
}
```

```html
<p class="description-wrapper trimmed-description-wrapper">
    <span class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam officiis quos totam. Cupiditate, dicta facere? Ab amet aspernatur atque beatae commodi deleniti dolores ea earum eos error maxime minus nemo neque nihil non, nostrum odio officiis optio perferendis reprehenderit saepe suscipit vero vitae? Cumque delectus distinctio dolore, dolorem ducimus facere laudantium neque nisi officiis! Ad consectetur rerum saepe voluptatibus? Cum dicta facere hic libero perspiciatis quae, quaerat quo quos reprehenderit sed totam vel. Consequuntur ea odit pariatur! Ab accusantium consequuntur, ea et exercitationem, illum, inventore molestias obcaecati officia optio praesentium quibusdam similique vel? Accusantium doloribus fuga ipsam neque, porro similique?
    </span>
    <span class="a read-more-link" onclick="this.parentNode.classList.remove('trimmed-description-wrapper');">read more</span>
</p>
```