# CSS Text ellipsis including "More" link

Tags: javascript, css, ellipsis

So I have the following Fiddle that has set an ellipsis in a text into two lines. Then I want to have a 'More' link inline with the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/csYjC/2876/

So if our text has more than two lines, it should look like this:

[image]

That's correct. However:

[image]

That's not correct (should be inline with the text).

Code is like follows:

```
<div class="text">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem Lorem i</div>
  <a href="#">More</a>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.text{
   display: inline;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   line-height: 24px;     /* fallback */
   max-height: 48px;      /* fallback */
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.text a {
    position: absolute;
}
```

I guess must be easy... Thank you in advance.

Comment: can't you put `a` in that `div`?

Comment: `if our text has more than two lines` => sounds like javascript. And you need events for when the user resizes the window (to keep correct behaviour)

Comment: That ellipsis property is taking care about the 2 lines... If I write the a inside the div... http://jsfiddle.net/csYjC/2879/ It's fine if the "More" is in the same line but if not, it's not.

Comment: Isn't that 'more' link going to always show, even if all content is displayed? (Unless you have JS to block?)

Comment: Ollie, your right, that might be another problem to solve. But I think easier problem, like when we click "More" we make this <a> to display none.

Comment: I did this yesterday for a project.

Comment: @FerranNegre will this work for u ?

Comment: Ten years after this was asked, I want to point out that link text like "More" is now considered to be [bad for accessibility](https://usability.yale.edu/web-accessibility/articles/links#link-text). Once you are aware of that, however, there _are_ ways to work around that... but you need to know that, or eventually someone will sue you for your inaccessible website/app.

Answer (score 0):

The div inside of `.text` is still being displayed as a block element. Use this to fix:

```
.text > div { display: inline; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csYjC/2880/

Comment: Hi, that put the "More" inline with the text in a correct way. But notice that if you resize the windows, the More is not in the right place (gets bit crazy). Moreover, I just realized that in Firefox, ellipsis is not working.

Comment: @FerranNegre Change to `.text a{position: relative;}` http://jsfiddle.net/hegsgwrv/

Comment: Hi. I tried that. Still not working. Now is always inline with the text (when I want it below when two lines are completed). If you resize it a lot, you will see that the 'More' link dissapears. And still not ellipsis with Firefox... that might be another thing.

Comment: @FerranNegre this won't work in Firefox because you are using the `-webkit` prefix only. Firefox doesn't use webkit.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure how to solve this without using Javascript. I assumed forcing a height on the inner div would solve your problem, but the clamp is overriding it. So far it seems Ollie's addition to my answer is the best possibility.

Comment: Ollie's solution does not show the More button when you re-size it very small (also not putting the link under when the text fits the two line). And there is also the Firefox problem... easy way to do it in JS?

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/hatuv/1/edit**

```
<div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem Lorem i </p>  <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text {
    overflow: hidden /* just for clearing */
}
.text p {
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 40px;
    margin-right: -40px;
}
.text a {
    float: right
}
```

Comment: That looks nice. Is it also possible to make the "More" button going under the text when the text is already fitting all the line? Moreover, you are using only 1 line, I am trying with 2 lines.

Comment: I couldn't get multi-line to work without a jQuery script, that's what I ended up using. jQuery Succinct plugin

Comment: @FerranNegre -- Firefox and multi-line gave me issues so I gave up and ended up using jQuery Succinct plugin

Comment: Do you have an example of it? Also with the "More" link? Just wanted to be inline the text when lines don't fit all space and under when they do. I thought could be done in pure CSS.

Comment: This is the only thing I found that works in Firefox too, it's a pain to implement and so I opted for jQuery, which does not reflow on resize, only on load. I don't care since barely anyone except for testers are sizing their viewports all over the place. http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

Comment: I see.. still that example has no 'More' button. I matter about 'resizing' cause it must be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

a pure css method base on -webkit-line-clamp, and you can custom the ...more content like a boss:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes ellipsis {/*for test*/
    0% { width: 622px }
    50% { width: 311px }
    100% { width: 622px }
}
.ellipsis {
    max-height: 40px;/* h*n */
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;

    -webkit-animation: ellipsis ease 5s infinite;/*for test*/
    /**
    overflow: visible;
    /**/
}
.ellipsis .content {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    font-size: 50px;/* w */
    line-height: 20px;/* line-height h */
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;/* max row number n */
    vertical-align: top;
}
.ellipsis .text {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}
.ellipsis .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    /**
    overflow: visible;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    /**/
}
.ellipsis .overlay:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;

    /**
    background: lightgreen;
    /**/
}
.ellipsis .placeholder {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;/* h*n */

    /**
    background: lightblue;
    /**/
}
.ellipsis .more {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;/* -h */
    left: -50px;/* -w */
    float: left;
    color: #000;
    width: 50px;/* width of the .more w */
    height: 20px;/* h */
    font-size: 14px;

    /**
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: orange;
    /**/
}
```

```html
<div class='ellipsis'>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='text'>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
            <div class='placeholder'></div>
            <div class='more'>...<a href="http://hai.li">more</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, but works only in webkit browsers. So not usable for production.

Answer (score 0):

well using flexbox make it simple. Try this around

```
.text {
  display: flex;
  > div {
    flex: 0 0 40%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/baagii95/pen/byeNqZ

btw i used sass. If you want in css version try this.

```
.text {
  display: flex;
}

.text > div {
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used canvas to get the width of the string occupied by the content in the div(as for different fonts there will be slight differences in the measurement).Here i calculated the number of lines in which the content is divided into by dividing the width of string(i.e content.textContent) by div content's width

The moment it reaches above or equal to 3 the display property of anchor tag would change to block and when it is less than 3 it would revert back to inline.

#### OUTPUT:

[image]

## This will work

```js
var content = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
var more = document.getElementsByClassName('more');

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var font = "30px times new roman";
context.font = font;
var text = content.textContent;
var width = context.measureText(text).width;
var w = Math.ceil(width);



window.onload = function() {
  change_more();
}

window.onresize = function() {
  change_more();
}


function change_more() {
  var check = Math.ceil(w / content.offsetWidth);

  if (check > 2) {
    more[0].style.display = "none";
    more[1].style.display = "block";
    content.style.textOverflow = "ellipsis";
  } else {
    more[0].style.display = "inline";
    more[1].style.display = "none";
    content.style.textOverflow = "clip";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* fallback */
  font-size: 30px;
  max-height: 90px;
  /* fallback */
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  /* number of lines to show */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

a {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="content" style="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#/" class="more">MORE</a></div>
  <a href="#/" class="more">MORE</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Not in firefox .

Comment: @QuestionsBoy what are you saying i checked it in firefox the moment content goes from more than second lines 'MORE' link position gets changed and changes back when it again is less than or ==2

Comment: @QuestionsBoy is it still not working in your firefox ?

Comment: At some point, the link disappears both on the right and at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a kind of a funny solution with pure CSS using pseudo elements.
http://jsfiddle.net/j8ekzvLq/

```
.text {
   display: inline;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   line-height: 24px;     /* fallback */
   max-height: 48px;      /* fallback */
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 24px;
}

.text::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

.text div {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.text div::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -24px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.text a::before {
    content: "More";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: If the background is semi-transparent, how do you obscure `.text a::before`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the problem cannot be solved without javascript.
It is necessary to calculate link position. One of the implementation options can be as follows (used jquery for convenience):

```js
positionMore();
$(window).on('resize', positionMore);

function positionMore(){
    $('.text').each(function(){
        const t = $(this);
        const container = t.closest('.container-text');
        const more = t.find('.text-more');
        if(
            Math.ceil(more.position()?.left + more.width()) > t.width() ||
            Math.ceil(more.position()?.top) >= t.height()
        ){
            container.addClass('active');
        }else{
            container.removeClass('active');
        }
    })
}
```

```css
.container-text > .text-more {
  display: none;
}
.container-text.active > .text-more {
  display: inline;
}
.container-text.active .text .text-more {
  opacity: 0;
}
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  line-height: 24px;
  /* fallback */
  max-height: 48px;
  /* fallback */
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  /* number of lines to show */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.text .text-more {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-text">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias eveniet sequi quos accusantium fuga corrupti voluptate nihil reprehenderit voluptatem tenetur, et modi nisi, consequatur dolore fugit iusto perferendis consequuntur illum, nemo esse natus fugiat? Et, ratione? Asperiores sequi, eaque ullam mollitia quos quidem vitae. Nihil velit provident accusamus est corporis nobis harum fugiat!&nbsp;
    <a href="#" class="text-more">More</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="text-more">More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An HTML element, such as a *"read more"* link can be visually rendered at the end of a **truncated** text block, in such a way the added element fits into the container and does not overlay the text (cover part of it) by utilizing a combination of "tricks":

### First Part - A pseudo-element

A pseudo-element is used with 3 properties, where the `--line-clamp` variable is also used by the container to indicate after which line to truncate:

```css
p::before {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  height: calc((var(--line-clamp) - 1) * 1lh);
}
```

### Second Part - The "show more" link

Place an anchor element `<a class='show-more'>Show More</a>` **before** any of the text within the container. The element
has to be the *first* node so it won't be trimmed and also so
it could be "floated" all the way to the right (in an LTR text)

```css
p .show-more {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
}
```

In the below example I am using *javascript* to detect when the text is being truncated (overflow its container):

### [Live Example](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/ExGwmJL):

```js
function isTextTruncated( elm ){
  const truncated = elm.scrollHeight > elm.clientHeight
  elm.classList.toggle('truncated', truncated)
}

// observe resize
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(m => isTextTruncated(m[0].target))

resizeObserver.observe(document.querySelector('p'), { attributes: true })
```

```css
p {
  --line-clamp: 4;
  
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: var(--line-clamp);
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  
  hyphens: auto;
  width: clamp(300px, 50%, 900px);
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p::before {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  height: calc((var(--line-clamp) - 1) * 1lh);
}

p .show-more {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  
  color: blue;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

/* 
  no need to render the "show more" link if 
  the text is fully-visible and not truncated
*/
p:not(.truncated) .show-more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a class='show-more'>Show More</a>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
</p>
```

#### Truncate if "text does not fit":

This is currently outside the scope of CSS capability, but here's a javascript polyfill I've created which limits a text to the height of its container and trim it with an ellipsis:

https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/eYbGgGL

Answer (score -3):

Just add to div some class and give it `display:inline;` :

```
<div class="text">
    <div class="loremclass">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <a href="#">More</a>
</div>
```

and

```
body {
   margin: 20px;
}

.text{
   display: inline;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   line-height: 24px;     /* fallback */
   max-height: 48px;      /* fallback */
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.text a {
    position: absolute;
}
.loremclass{display:inline;}
```

Comment: That does not put the 'More' link inline the text when the text is not fitting all 2 lines.

Comment: Yea now is like we tried before. The 'More' gets in crazy position when is not inline with the text (re-size the window to see it).

Comment: This is a duplicate of my answer except you've added an arbitrary class for the inner div.

Comment: @88 MPG and that is the reason you gived me -? I didn't look at you solution

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why. In the future, please read all current answers before posting an answer. If someone has posted your solution and you have something to add, comment on the existing answer. If you agree with the answer, vote for it.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted it please edit the question